# fancybox - adding class to iframe for styling

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I wanted to ask if it's possible do add some class to fancybox, to do some actions.

Now i have something like:

```
<a href="examplevideoformhost/tyut" class="fancybox.iframe"></i>show movie</a>
```

And

some default simple code to open movie on page start:

This Javascript is inside generic fancybox function

```
    $('fancybox.iframe').trigger('click');
```

And this works, on page load fancybox is shown.

But now i want for example to do something with this fancybox, for example on scroll page down, move fancybox right, but this can't be done, as i can't find method to select this element by Jquery, for more advanced actions...

So, i want to add some class for example and then use this as selector for Jquery.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the wrapCSS - option of fancybox (compare here: http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs) and assign a class to the fancybox.

```
    $('fancybox.iframe').fancybox({
        wrapCSS : 'someClass' });
```

Then call the class with jQuery.

```
$('.someClass').doSomething();
```